# classification on either feature sets is good but on the combination feature set is bad

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have two feature sets: f1 and f2. The size of data is 1.4 million. Only using f1, I trained random forest and tested on the testing set. The accuracy is 79%. Then I only used f2 and tested on the same testing set. The accuracy is 79.5%. However, when I merged f1 and f2 into one feature vector and ran the same experiment. The accuracy is 80.4%.

Then I ran this test. I first only used f1 and trained random forest and tested on the testing set. I collected the data which I cannot classify them correctly, which is called S1. Then I used f2 only and split the collected dataset S1 into training and testing sets. The accuracy for this testing set is 86%.

From my experiment result, could anyone tell me what is wrong ? Why is the accuracy low when I merged feature sets f1 and f2?

Comment: The accuracy is not low, its ~ 1% higher than using individual feature sets. Also, on S1, you get only 86% accuracy, which is only 7% higher than using f1. So if you take a weighted average of 79 and 86, is it near 80-81%? (assuming S1 has less amount of data).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have over-fitting (variance). I recommend you try feature selection algorithm to be ran on F1unionF2 to get a subset of features from F1 and from F2. You can read more about the subject in [Stanford cs229 notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials.html)

Lecture 4 describes bias vs variance and lecture 5 describe model selection including feature selection.
You also have the video lectures of cs229 in YouTube and another version in coursera.